# Bootstrap grid padding not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap grid system for building a website, i'm not using the row class but the padding between divs is not working!

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Just like 4 divs,
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
divs with height, and thats it

Comment: @ArditAvdylaj Please make a jsfiddle with a full example showing what you see and explain what you are expecting to see. You need to be much more specific in your problem description.

Comment: Edit the question, add your code, provide a http://bootply.com/ example where it demonstrates your issue. However, please keep in mind that the bootstrap cols needed to be surrounded by a `row` class div.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `.row` class? `col-*` is [always supposed to be inside `row`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Why not using row? Is mandatory if you don't want to deal with multiple problems.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap there are 12 columns in a row. You have 4 * 4 = 16, and that's not correct.

> It’s based on a 12 column layout and has multiple tiers, one for each media query range.

So you should change your code to:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

See docs [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 0):

To start with - assuming you are wanting a single row- you need to either change these divs to a "3" each or have one less of them - remember that 12 is the magic number for the Bootstrap grid.

Also the reason for containing the cols in a .row is to control the margin on either side. The padding is INSIDE the divs - not between them so the following will give you a row with 3 divs that are positioned adjacent to each other to give a full row and will have left / right padding of 15px inside each div:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The .row class has a -15px margin on either side so that each of the side divs will aligns with the edge of the parent container div. Remember that you can use container-fluid to expand the parent div across the entire viewport.

So to summarise - the Bootstrap .col-* divs do NOT have padding between them, but rather padding inside them. Unless of course your CSS overrides that.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

1. Row is mandatory
2. Every row has 12 columns

You are using 16 columns, change your code to:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```